# How to get oracle error while execute .sql file

Tags: java, sql, oracle

How could I get oracle error, when I am executing an .sql file that do for me i.e. `Alter` and when an error occurs let's say the `&3` parameter was wrong then an oracle exception is thrown. How could I get this exception from command line to java? Is there a possibility to do that or rather no?

Comment: Are you trying to launch _SQL*Plus_ from java code?

Answer (score 0):

To have SQL*Plus return the error code, start the script with `whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;`.  I'm not sure how Java works\ with operating system return codes, but here's an example showing it working on the DOS command prompt:

```
SQL> whenever sqlerror exit sql.sqlcode;
SQL> select * from dual where this_column_doesnt_exist = 1;
select * from dual where this_column_doesnt_exist = 1
                         *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "THIS_COLUMN_DOESNT_EXIST": invalid identifier


Disconnected from Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

C:\>echo Exit Code is %errorlevel%
Exit Code is 904
```